# Connect view to collection in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a view that renders a template with a inputfield. When text gets typed into the inputfield it activates a event that creates a new View and append it to a element that's being renderd in this view.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Moviesearch extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/moviesearch']
  el: '#moviesearch'

  initialize: (opts) ->
    {@collection} = opts
    @render()
    return

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    return

  events:
    "keyup input": "doSearch"

  doSearch: (e) ->
    @collection.setQuery $(e.currentTarget).val()
    @collection.fetch()
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Searchresult()
    $('#movies').append(view.render().el)
```

If I'm correct the view and collection are "linked" because of the `Moviesearch` name.

But for my Searchresult view I'm using this. And I think I'm not "linking" this to my Moviesearch collection.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Searchresult extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/searchresult']

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template(movie: @collection))
    this
```

In the template I render I have this code,

```
Movie result template

<% for movie in @movie.results : %> 
    <li><%= movie.original_title %></li> 
<% end %>
```

But when the template gets rendered I get a error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    (anonymous function) 
    (anonymous function) 
    JST.movieseats/searchresult 
    Movieseat.Views.Searchresult.Searchresult.render 
    Movieseat.Views.Moviesearch.Moviesearch.doSearch 
    jQuery.event.dispatch 
    elemData.handle
```

Am I correct to think this is a problem with connecting the the searchresult view with the moviesearch collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know coffeescript, so I'll write in javascript.

There are a couple of things :

First, Collection fetch is asynchronous by default, so render view only when fetch has completed.

```
this.collection.fetch().done(function(){
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Searchresult()
    $('#movies').append(view.render().el)
});
```

Second, pass the collection to the view

```
view = new Movieseat.Views.Searchresult({collection:collection});
```

Third, Save the collection reference

```
Movieseat.Views.Searchresult = Backbone.view.extend({
  initialize:function(opts){
    this.collection = opts.collection;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `@template(@collection)` instead of just `@template()`

Comment: I've changed `render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())` to `render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@collection))` In my `class Movieseat.Views.Moviesearch` but I'm still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined ` error. How does the `class Movieseat.Views.Searchresult w` know what collection to use?